# How to handle a rails endless / infinite process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-sqs

I'm working with Amazon SQS queues and I have a class that consumes the messages on the queue. I am trying to get the messages consumed as close to real time as possible so I need the consuming code to be endlessly run. There will be messages on the queue consistently for more than half the day.

There are a few solutions I have come across to run this endlessly and I am wondering if there is a best practice for this type of need.

Option 1

On the web server use delayed_job or sidekiq to run the process continuously in the background.

Option 2

Have a separate server have a ruby application dedicated to consuming the messages.

Option 3

Placing the SQS consumer in a rake task and using a system call to fire off the task in the background.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/).

It will consume your messages continuously until your queue has messages.

```
shoryuken -r your_worker.rb -C shoryuken.yml \
  -l log/shoryuken.log -p shoryuken.pid -d
```

Comment: Wanted to comment on this since I've been using shoryuken for a while now. SQS message processing through shoryuken is solid and takes care of all of the dirty work involved with SQS. Using the delay = 0 option allows us to process queues close to real time. There is also an integration with capistrano that works relatively well too.

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably already discovered, there isn't one obvious **right way™** to handle this kind of thing. It depends a lot on what work you do for each job, the size of your app and infrastrucure, and your personal preferences on APIs, message queuing philosophies, and architecture.

That said, I'd probably lean towards option 2 based on your description. Sidekiq and delayed_job don't speak SQS, and while you could teach them with something like [sidekiq-sqs](https://github.com/jmoses/sidekiq-sqs), it sounds like you might outgrow them pretty quick. Unless you need your Rails environment available to your workers, you'd have better luck separating your queue consumers into distinct applications, which makes it easy to scale horizontally just by starting more processes. It also allows you to further decouple the workers from your Rails app, which can make things easier to deploy and administer.

Option 3 is a non-starter IMO. You'll want to have a daemon running to process jobs as they come in, and if rake has to load your environment on each job, things are going to get sloooow.